# Not able to convert a string to integer. Sometime getting NumberFormatException

Tags: java, string, exception, if-statement, numberformatexception

I am trying to get massage count, notification count and friend request count from a facebook account. After getting the string data from facebook i am converting it into interger by using Interger.parseInt(String) method. As per my code logic i am putting the data i am getting from facebook inside error, error1 and error2 when they are a string and after converting them into interger i am putting them inside actualfriend, actualmassage and actualnotification. At the end i am comparing the actual data with some expected data.

The problem is i am getting correct results for massage count but for friend request and notification i am getting correct data in error1 and error2 but once i convert them into an integer from string them i gets actualfriend=0 and actualnotification=0.

```
 public  void operation() throws InterruptedException, AWTException ,StaleElementReferenceException,NoSuchElementException,NumberFormatException {
      int i=1;
      int j=1;
      while(i==1){
      String error = "1";
      String error1= "1";
      String error2= "1";
      System.out.println(error);
      if((error.length() != 0) && (error1.length() != 0) && (error2.length() != 0)){ 
      try{
       actualmassage = Integer.parseInt(error);
        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          error="5";
           try{ 
            actualnotification=Integer.parseInt(error1);
             }catch(NumberFormatException ee){
              error1="5";
               try{ 
                actualfriend=Integer.parseInt(error2);
                 }catch(NumberFormatException eee){
                   error2="5";
                 }//catch3
               }//catch2
           }//catch3
      }//if for massage 
      else if((error.length() !=0) && (error1.length() !=0) && (error2.length() !=0)){
          actualmassage = Integer.parseInt(error);
          actualnotification = Integer.parseInt(error1);
          actualfriend = Integer.parseInt(error2);
      }//else if
      else{

      }//else
      int expectedmassage =1;
      int expectednotification=0;
      int expectedfriend=0;
      if(expectedmassage == actualmassage ){
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          System.out.println("Readable Massage = "+error +" actualmassage = "+actualmassage);
      }else{
          System.outprintln("Does't Match");
          i++;
      }//else
      if(expectednotification == actualnotification){
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          System.out.println("Total Notification = "+error1 +" actualnotification = "+actualnotification);
      }else{
          System.outprintln("Does't Match");
          i++;
      }//else
      if(expectedfriend == actualfriend ){
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          System.out.println("Total FriendRequest = "+error2 +" actualfriend = "+actualfriend);
      }else{
          System.outprintln("Does't Match");
          i++;
      }//else

    //Counting number of runs
      System.out.println("Number of run = " + j);
      j++;
      }//while
      System.out.println("Stop");
      i=(i+2);  
 }//operation
public static void main(String[] args) throws StaleElementReferenceException, InterruptedException, AWTException,NoSuchElementException,NumberFormatException{
    fb c = new fb();
   }//main
  }//calss

Output for this-
1
Readable Massage = 1 actualmassage = 1
Total Notification = 1 actualnotification = 0
Total FriendRequest = 1 actualfriend = 0
Number of run = 1
1
Readable Massage = 1 actualmassage = 1
Total Notification = 1 actualnotification = 0
Total FriendRequest = 1 actualfriend = 0
Number of run = 2
```

As you can see i am getting- Readable Massage = 1(getting from error variable) actualmassage = 1(getting from actualmassage after converting it to integer from string). Total Notification = 1(getting from error1 variable) actualnotification = 0(getting from actualmassage after converting it to integer from string) which is wrong. Total FriendRequest = 1(getting from error2 variable) actualfriend = 0(getting from actualfriend after converting it to integer from string) which is wrong.

changed the code from-

```
      int expectedmassage =1;
      int expectednotification=0;
      int expectedfriend=0;
      if(expectedmassage == actualmassage ){
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          System.out.println("Readable Massage = "+error +" actualmassage = "+actualmassage);
      }else{
          System.out.print("Does't match");
          i++;
      }//else
      if(expectednotification == Integer.parseInt(error1)){
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          System.out.println("Total Notification = "+error1 +" actualnotification = "+actualnotification);
      }else{
          System.out.print("Does't match");
          i++;
      }//else
      if(expectedfriend == Integer.parseInt(error2)){
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          System.out.println("Total FriendRequest = "+error2 +" actualfriend = "+actualfriend);
      }else{
          System.out.print("Does't match");
          i++;
      }//else
```

But after doing this i got-

```
 1
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at com.selenium.fb.main1(fb.java:103)
at com.selenium.fb.main(fb.java:123)
```

Comment: Your question looks as if it was created by some text generator. The minimum you can do is go over your question and ask yourself if it's readable and what can you do to improve it. Hints: start by explaining the problem **clearly*. Remove all unnecessary code - use minimal code example that can show how to reproduce the problem, etc.

Comment: @ alfasin I changed the format of question Sir

Comment: What happens in line `fb.java:103` ? looks like you're trying to parseInt an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the first if(error.length() != 0) && (error1.length() != 0) && (error2.length() != 0) is failing to assign values to actualnotification and actualfriend because it is not reaching them.Change the code with below code. I created separate if block for each and it worked.

```
     try{
       actualmassage = Integer.parseInt(error);
        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          error="0";
        }//catch1
      }//if1
         if((error1.length() != 0)){
           try{ 
            actualnotification=Integer.parseInt(error1);
             }catch(NumberFormatException ee){
              error1="0";
               }//catch2
           }//if2   
        if((error2.length() != 0)){ 
              try{
                   actualfriend=Integer.parseInt(error2);
                 }catch(NumberFormatException eee){
                   error2="0";
                 }//catch3
                }//if3
```